# unable to render index or mobile page with spring mobile

Tags: spring-boot

I was able to get my project to run just fine until I brought in spring-mobile. Now only Strings will return in the browser that the spring-mobile method is returning:

```
@Controller
public class DeviceDetection {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeviceDetection.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public String detectDevice(Device device) {

        if (device.isNormal()) {
            System.out.println("Inside isNormal()");
            return "index";
        } else if (device.isMobile()) {
            System.out.println("Inside isMobile()");
            return "mobilePage";
        } else if (device.isTablet()) {
            return "mobilePage";
        }
        return "index";
    }

}
```

So I decided I needed internalResourceViewResolver but that just gives me the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in class path resource    


    [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoCon 
figurationAdapter.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is   
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mobile
```

and

```
   DeviceDelegatingViewResolverAutoConfiguration$DeviceDelegatingViewResolverConfigur
ation$InternalResourceViewResolverDelegateConfiguration.viewResolver; nested   
exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 
[org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver] is 
defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: 
getViewResolver,defaultViewResolver
```

Resolver class

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StidhamFinancialApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(StidhamFinancialApplication.class);

        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
       System.out.println(String.format("Access URLs:\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
                "Local: \t\thttp://127.0.0.1:%1s\n\t" +
                "External: \thttp://%2s:%3s\n----------------------------------------------------------",
            env.getProperty("server.port"),
            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
            env.getProperty("server.port")));
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(StidhamFinancialApplication.class);
    }
}
```

project structure:

[image]

I am running it on Tomcat 8...

--------Update 1---------------
I deleted my configuration package and add `@ResponeBody` to my detectDevice method like so:

```
//If I remove @ResponseBody it complains of a Circular view path [index] with    
@ResponseBody it just renders a String and not a view

@RequestMapping(value="/index")
public @ResponseBody String detectDevice(Device device) { 

    if (device.isNormal()) {
        System.out.println("Inside isNormal()");
        return "index";
    } else if (device.isMobile()) {
        System.out.println("Inside isMobile()");
        return "mobilePage";
    } else if (device.isTablet()) {
        return "mobilePage";
    }
    return "index";
}
```

Only the String `index` or `mobilePage` will render in the browser. If I delete the `@ResponseBody` then the project gives an error saying the following:

```
2016-05-29 08:55:03.682 ERROR 8230 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page 
from request [/index.html] due to exception [Circular view path 
[index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index] again. 
Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an 
unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)]
```

If I remove the `/index` then the method is ignored completely and spring-boot just maps my index file and works again but I need the mobile site to work.

-------------------UPDATE 2-------------------

Ok I added thymeleaf and my index page is rendering again. Even better the `DeviceDetection` is working but once my project looks for my `mobilePage` I get the following error:

```
Error resolving template "mobile/index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I had to add the follow ing `@Configuration` to get the project to work. The spring-boots defaultViewResolver was causing me to many issues. Here is the project structure now:

[image]

I updated the project on GIT too.

Comment: Spring Boot already creates an `InternalResourceViewResolver` for you, so yours is actually breaking things. You don't need your `MvcConfiguration`. All of that is already done by Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes I know but since it was not working I thought maybe since I was using spring-mobile and now had a few views I needed it. I was just trying to show SOF my thought process and what I have done so far to solve it. Please see update 1.

Comment: `/index.html` matches `/index`. Also your view mapping isn't what you have in your structure. The views aren't in `/WEB-INF` they are directly accessible. Instead use something like thyme leaf and put them in `src/main/resources/templates`. Currently there is no view found and it will redirect back to the handler (which is also what your error is telling you).

Comment: @M.Deinum please see update 2. I am getting closer but still having a lot of  issues.

Comment: I suggest a read of the reference guide. The mobile pages need to go in a sub dir named `mobile` and for tablet in `tablet` (those are the default values) . Basically you don't need to differ based on the type of device as that is already done for you.

Comment: Solved, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I needed to use something like Thymeleaf and create a viewResolver. Spring-boots defaultViewResolver was causing me issues:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet(){
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();

        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        return dispatcherServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Since I was using Thymeleaf I needed bindingResult and a few other things. This is also where I implemented springs mobile `Device` interface to detect the device.

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contactForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("person") Contact contact, BindingResult bindingResult,
                              HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Device device) throws IOException {

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("There was a error "+bindingResult);
            return "error";
        }

        model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());

        if(device.isNormal()){
            System.out.println("I am normal");
            return "index";
        } else if(device.isMobile()){
            System.out.println("I am a mobile");
            return "mobilePage";
        } else if (device.isTablet()){
            System.out.println("I am a tablet");
            return "mobilePage";
        }

        return "index";
    }
```

Now I just needed to put the different views in the correct directories like so:

[image]

That was it and it is working perfectly.

Here is the form I created to use implement Thymeleaf:

```
<!-- Contact form -->
<form action="#" th:action="@{/contact}" th:object="${contact}" method="POST" class="contact-form clear-fix">

<div class="clear-fix">

    <ul class="list-0 clear-fix">
        <!-- Name -->
    <li>
    <div class="block field-box">
     <label for="contact-form-name" class="text-color-black">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="contact noMarr col-md-6 text-color-black" id="contact-form-name" />
    </div>
    </li>
<!-- /Name -->
<!-- E-mail address -->
<li>
<div class="block field-box">
 <label for="contact-form-mail" class="text-color-black">Your E-mail</label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{email}" class="contact noMarr col-md-6 text-color-black" id="contact-form-mail" />
</div>
</li>
 <!-- /E-mail address -->
<!-- Website URL -->
<li>
<div class="block field-box">
<label for="contact-form-subject" class="text-color-black">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{subject}" class="contact noMarr col-md-6 text-color-black" id="contact-form-subject" />
</div>
    </li>
<!-- /Website URL -->
    <!-- Message -->
    <li>
<div class="block field-box ">
<label for="contact-form-message" class="text-color-black">Your message</label>
<textarea name="comment" class="contact col-md-12 text-color-black" th:field="*{message}" id="contact-form-message"></textarea>
</div>
</li>
<!-- /Message -->
<!-- Submit button -->
<li>
<div class="block field-box field-box-button text-color-black">
    <input type="submit" id="contact-form-submit" name="contact-form-submit" class="button text-color-black" value="Submit"/>
</div>
</li>
 <!-- /Submit button -->
 </ul>
 </div>
 </form>
```